# Why this output is generated by the following code, why not error/exception is generated?

Tags: java

```
class VarAgs{

    // variable length parameters
    static void vaTest(String ... str){
        System.out.println(str.length + " contains : ");
        for(String s:str){  
            System.out.print(s+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1[] = {"hi","hello"};
        vaTest(s1);
        vaTest(s1 + " 1 ");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2 contains : 
hi hello 
1 contains : 
[Ljava.lang.String;@2a139a55 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What exception would you expect, and why? Note that in the second call to `vaTest` you're passing a single string, so it's equivalent to `vaTest(new String[] { s1 + " 1 " })`

Comment: Because of arrays return it's type and memory address.

Answer (score 0):

When you concatenate an array with a string in

```
    vaTest(s1 + " 1 ");
```

Then the reference to the array is converted into a string

```
 [Ljava.lang.String;@2a139a55
```

So the method vaTest will receive the

`[Ljava.lang.String;@2a139a55 1`

as an array with size of 1.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `vaTest(s1 + " 1 ");`, a string representation of s1 would be used because of [string concatenation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) rules ("+" sign). So instead of a formatted array you get some kind of that:  `[Ljava.lang.String;@2a139a55`

Replace it with `vaTest(Arrays.toString(s1) + " 1 ");` to get expected result.

Answer (score 0):

It works as following:

1. `s1` is implicitly converted to String (`s1.toString()`), this results in `[Ljava.lang.String;@2a139a55`.
2. Next, string `1` is added to the above string. This results in `[Ljava.lang.String;@2a139a55 1`
3. Next, this resulting string is passed inside single-element array of type String[] into `varargs()` function.